# How to add javascript js files into qmldir with qt_add_qml_module

Tags: cmake, qml, qmllint

I am creating a Qt6 QML module with qt_add_qml_module.

```
qt_add_qml_module(SQUtils_Logger_Qml
    URI SQUtilsLogger.Qml
    VERSION 1.0
    SOURCES
        LoggerQml.cpp
    QML_FILES
        Log.js
        Logm.mjs
        LoggerQml.qml
        )
```

But the generated `qmldir` contains only the information about the qml file: **the js and mjs files are missing**.

```
module SQUtils.Logger.Qml
linktarget SQUtils_Logger_Qmlplugin
optional plugin SQUtils_Logger_Qmlplugin
classname SQUtils_Logger_QmlPlugin
typeinfo SQUtils_Logger_Qml.qmltypes
prefer :/SQUtils/Logger/Qml/
LoggerQml 1.0 LoggerQml.qml
```

It is a problem because when I run `ninja all_qmllint`, the compiler/linter complains that Log is not defined:

```
// View.qml
import SQUtils_Logger_Qml
//import "qrc:/SQUtils/Logger/Qml/Log.js" as Log

ApplicationWindow {
    Component.onCompleted: {
            Log.debug("QML main application complete")
        }
}
```

```sh
Warning: View.qml:120:13: Unqualified access
            Log.debug("QML main application complete)
```

If I append `Log 1.0 Log.js` to the `qmldir` file, then the linting works.

What I am doing wrong? Is this a bug? The qt documentation for [qt_add_qml_module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-qml-module.html) quotes:

```
QML_FILES lists the .qml, .js and .mjs files for the module. [...] 
The files will also be used to populate type information in the generated qmldir file.
```

Thank you for your help!

Note: I can manage to run my code by uncommenting `import "qrc:/SQUtils/Logger/Qml/Log.js" as Log`, but the lint still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a Qt bug, corrected two days ago. It will be corrected in versions greater than 6.2.2:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-100326